# Nginx - regex location

Tags: regex, nginx, lua, nginx-location, openresty

So I have a regex-based location rule, something like this:

```
location ~ /(abc.*xyz|def.*zxy|ghk.*qwe)/
```

Can I check which part of regex yielded the match?
Meaning that if the url was like

```
/12abc34/
```

Than I'd like to know that it was matched by

```
.*abc.*
```

Is there a way?

I'm running latest nginx compiled with lua-module on a Debian VM on AWS.

------------Update-------------

I'm thinking to use inner location, but it will be ugly:

```
 location ~ /(abc.*xyz|def.*zxy|ghk.*qwe)/
{
    location ~ /(abc.*xyz){...}
    location ~ /(def.*zxy){...}
...
}
```

Right now I have like 60 regex patterns. Is such approach ok?

Comment: Have you considered using `map` with `$request_uri`? See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression expression: `/(.*abc.*|.*def.*|.*ghk.*)/` can be reduced to:

```
location ~ (abc|def|ghk).*/ { ... }
```

As any `nginx` URI begins with a `/`, you do not need to test for `/.*`.

The part of the regular expression within parentheses is *captured* as `$1` within the `location` block.

So in the case of `/12abc34/`, the variable `$1` would be set to `abc`.

Comment: Ok, but I also have rules like (xyz.*abc). The solution you offered unfortunatelly will not work for this :(